# Calling formatting in python to conjugate verbs

Tags: python, list, tuples

I'm trying to get a print of the verb to be in English conjugated by python

My code is:

```
verbFormat = ["I","you","he","she","we","they","yee",]
verbConjBePresent = [{0} + "am", {1} "are", {2} "is", {3} "is", {4} "are", {5} "are", {6} "are",]
print(verbConjBePresent.format(verbFormat))
```

I have tried adding {x} + "str" in the vCBP and tried without.

I have tried using tuples instead of lists

EDIT: The Reason I want to use the list "verbFormat" is so I don't need to re-iterate those words every time I change verb (and it should cover most tenses for most verbs)

EDIT 2: In the interest of anyone searching this topic in the future I would like to add the code to the point of being able to pick a conjugation with a var[x]

```
verbFormat = ["I","you","he","she","we","they","yee",]
verbConjBePresent = "{} am; {} are; {} is; {} is; {} are; {} are; {} are"
verbBePresent =(verbConjBePresent.format(*verbFormat).split(';'))
print(verbBePresent[0])
```

Comment: What is the problem you are having?

Comment: I would like to be able to call the nth itteration of a verb, in this case "to be" in order to form sentences at a later date. I plan on itterating a few verbs (maybe the most common 100? in all tenses)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your string formatting is wrong. You're trying to format a `list`.

```
verbFormat = ["I","you","he","she","we","they","yee"]
verbConjBePresent = "{0} am;{1} are;{2} is;{3} is;{4} are;{5} are;{6} are"
print(verbConjBePresent.format(verbFormat).split(';'))
```

With the `split(';')` you will print a list with conjugations. If you want all together in a string, just remove split.

Comment: This is a great answer, the split is a very interesting command I didn't know about. Thank you for your input as this makes the whole job easier :)

Answer (score 0):

Just use a string and unpack the list using str.format:

```
verbFormat = ["I","you","he","she","we","they","yee",]
verbConjBePresent = "{} am, {} are, {} is, {} is, {} are, {} are, {} are."
print(verbConjBePresent.format(*verbFormat))
```

Which will give you:

```
I am, you are, he is, she is, we are, they are, yee are.
```

*str.format* works on strings not lists.

Comment: No worries, you only need to use numbering with str.format for python < 2.7

Answer (score 0):

Is this the string you want as output?

```
'I am, you are, he is, she is, we are, they are, yee are'
```

Here is code to make it:

```
verbConjBePresent = '{0} am, {1} are, {2} is, {3} is, {4} are, {5} are, {6} are'
print(verbConjBePresent.format(*verbFormat))
```